# Athena InvalidRequestException from Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-athena, botocore

I am trying to read CSV file from S3 bucket and create table in Athena through Python. But I am getting below on executing it -

---

Start of DB Query

{'QueryExecutionId': '9cc82243-4220-47d0-8b63-0aa4f01fd590', 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '1c74bec6-663a-42ef-b9d1-73c7372eb4e1', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'date': 'Thu, 08 Nov 2018 15:37:11 GMT', 'x-amzn-requestid': '1c74bec6-663a-42ef-b9d1-73c7372eb4e1', 'content-length': '59', 'connection': 'keep-alive'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}

Start of table creation

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/Doc/PycharmProjects/aws-athena-repo/athena/app.py", line 61, in 
    QueryExecutionContext={'Database': 'athenadb'})

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 320, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 623, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)

botocore.errorfactory.InvalidRequestException: An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the StartQueryExecution operation: line 1:8: no viable alternative at input 'CREATE EXTERNAL'

---

Here is my code sample --

```
print("Start of DB Query")
# Create a new database
db_query = 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS athenadb;'
response = client.start_query_execution(
    QueryString=db_query,
    ResultConfiguration={'OutputLocation': 's3://mybucket'})
print(response)

table_query = '''
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `athenadb.testtable`(
    `id` int,
    `ident` string,
    `type` string,
    `name` string,
    `latitude_deg` double,
    `longitude_deg` double,
    `continent` string,
    `iso_country` string,
    `iso_region` string,
    `municipality` string,
    `scheduled_service` string,
    `gps_code` string,
    `iata_code` string,
    `local_code` string,
    `home_link` string,
    `wikipedia_link` string,
    `keywords` string 
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'escape.delim'='\\')
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 's3://mybucket/folder/' ;'''

print("Start of table creation")

response1 = client.start_query_execution(
    QueryString=table_query,
    ResultConfiguration={'OutputLocation': 's3://mybucket'},
    QueryExecutionContext={'Database': 'athenadb'})
print(response1)
```

I am not sure if the problem is with ROW FORMAT DELIMITED or else.
I think my code is fine.

Detailed steps would be appreciated!

Thanks in adavace!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used all the fields as String and SERDEPROPERTIES as OpenCSVSerde